# How to inject lines to interactive Python programmatically?

Tags: python

Consider this small interactive Python session:

```
>>> a = 'a'
>>> b = 'b'
>>> ab = a + b
>>> ab
'ab'
```

Is there any way to do that programmatically? I want to inject line per line and unit test the result in the end. I can not create a Python script and execute it like usual case because there is some code that reacts differently in interactive Python (for example, inspect.getcomments()). I want to test the behaviour in interactive Python. I prefer Python3 solution, but I suspect that the solution would not be different with the one in Python2.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... can you give more detail?  Why are you unit testing code input by a user?

Comment: [Doctest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html)?

Comment: @SethMMorton: For example: http://bugs.python.org/issue16355. I want to unit test the behaviour of inspect.getcomments() in interactive python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be with Python's [doctest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html) module. It essentially parses code as if it were in a Python REPL and then asserts that the output matches what was written in that REPL.

```
$ cat foo
>>> a = 'a'
>>> b = 'b'
>>> ab = a + b
>>> ab
'ab'
$ python -m doctest foo
$ cat > bar
>>> a = 'a'
>>> b = 'b'
>>> ab = b + a # oops
>>> ab
'ab'
$ python -m doctest bar
**********************************************************************
File "bar", line 4, in bar
Failed example:
    ab
Expected:
    'ab'
Got:
    'ba'
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   4 in bar
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```